# Javascript Round to 2 Decimals

Tags: javascript

I am looking to round the DistanceInput.value and DistanceInput1.value to 2 Decimals such as 1.80 and/or 11.80 etc...

Thanks

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000 * 0.62137119;
    distanceInput1.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000 * 0.62137119 + 1.00;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the question therefore it is not a duplicate as far as im aware.

Comment: It would be better to create a new question rather than completely change this one as the existing answers now make no sense.

Comment: No worries. I'll roll back your change and you can just create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.toFixed()` method

```
var num = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000 * 0.62137119;
distanceInput.value = num.toFixed(2);
```

See more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: I know the OP is asking about two decimals. This is just a warning for others who need more precision: `(0.3).toFixed(17) === "0.29999999999999999"` and `(0.1+0.2).toFixed(17) === "0.30000000000000004"` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: This has worked, Thanks for that.

I will edit the post as i am struggling outputting it to PHP

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the accuracy you need.

```
function toTwo() {    
    return +(Math.round(number + "e+2")  + "e-2");
}
```

or

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

Found another helpful one, if the float is a text.

If String

```
parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
```

If Number

```
num = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(valueToRound).toFixed(2);`

e.g. `distanceInput.value = (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000 * 0.62137119).toFixed(2);`